# php pdo execute array quotations

Tags: php

The below prepared statement doesn't insert into the database.

```
$sid =1;
$sid2 = $GET['sid2']; //empty
$position = 0;
$name = "John";

$new = $connectdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('',:sid,:sid2,:position,:name)");
                $new->execute(array(':sid'=>$sid,':sid2'=>$sid2,':position'=>$position,':name'=>$name));
```

When i add quotations to execute array values, then the insert works.

```
$new->execute(array(':sid'=>"$sid",':sid2'=>"$sid2",':position'=>"$position",':name'=>"$name"));
```

What i want to know is by adding quotations does this affect PDO's sanitization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only difference** in your case is `$sid2` and `"$sid2"`.

If `$sid2` is a string, then `$sid2` is same with `"$sid2"`, but when `$sid2` is `null`, then thing changed. If `$sid2` is **`null`**, then `"$sid2"` will be **empty string `""`**.

If your column for `sid2` has `NOT NULL` constraint, then you will failed to insert a null value, but you could insert empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Myabe you should try to:

```
$new->execute(
 array(
  ':sid'=>$connectdb->quote($sid),
  ':sid2'=>$connectdb->quote($sid2),
  ':position'=>$connectdb->quote($position),
  ':name'=>$connectdb->quote($name),
 )
);
```

Comment: For prepared statement, you should not do quote.